# App is closing when I change theme in Android

Tags: java, android, themes

I am trying to change app theme based on user selection, When user selects option from the list my app closes but in console no error or exception is shown. I want to change app theme like dark, light and system

SettingsFragmentNew.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.preference.ListPreference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragmentNew extends PreferenceFragmentCompat  {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

        ListPreference themePreference = findPreference("theme");
        themePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.equals("system")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
            } else if (newValue.equals("light")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
            } else if (newValue.equals("dark")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }    
}
```

XML file

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<PreferenceCategory app:title="General">

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="system"
        app:entries="@array/theme_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/theme_values"
        app:key="theme"
        app:title="Theme"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory app:title="Account">

    <Preference
        app:key="sign_out"
        app:title="Sign Out" />

    <Preference
        app:key="delete_account"
        app:title="Delete Account" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```